# Accessing HOME path in sublime text 2 command

Tags: sublimetext2

I want to have a simple sublime-command to open a specific (dot config) file in my home folder. Is there a variable or other magic I can use like ${packages}, but for the user's home folder?

Currently I have (Default.sublime-commands)

```
{
    "caption": "Edit my config",
    "command": "open_file",
    "args": {
        "file": "/Users/MyName/.myconfig"
    }
}
```

but want to get rid of the hard coded user name.

Unfortunately I can't find anything in the api "documentation" of sublime.

Comment: Don't know if it will work, but try: `"file": sublime.packages_path() + "Users/MyName/.myconfig"` in the args section

Comment: It's not that I want to have the packages path, that would be possible with ${packages}, but want to have something like ${home} (which doesn't work) for the user's home dir.

Comment: What about ~? Let the OS do the work?

Comment: Of course, I tried ~ first, but it doesn't work.

Comment: It looks like Sublime doesn't allow shell expansions, and can't access  shell variables.  I suppose you could write an external shell script, but that seems silly.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using custom command like this:

```python
import sublime_plugin, getpass

class OpenCustomFileCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
  def run(self, file_name):
    if("{username}" in file_name):
      file_name = file_name.replace("{username}", getpass.getuser())
    self.window.open_file(file_name)
```

and the following (Default.sublime-commands):

```json
{
  "caption": "Edit my config",
  "command": "open_custom_file",
  "args": { "file_name": "/Users/{username}/.myconfig" }
}
```

And of course you can **extend** OpenCustomFileCommand with your own replacements.

P.S. Command must be stored within Packages directory of ST2, i.e. in file **open_custom_file.py**